# Opposite operation to "rails new"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`rails new` creates a new Rails application, the entire Rails directory structure. But is there an opposite operation of `rails new`? The command that would delete what the `rails new` created. Or may I have just manually delete the directory the `rails new` generated?

`rails destroy` is not an option here. It is the opposite of `rails generate`, it only destroys separate components of MyApp but not the whole MyApp/.

Comment: yep, you can just delete the directory created.

Comment: why not just `rm -rf dirname`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply remove the folder.

If you're on an unix based system, use `rm`

```
rm -r your_rails_app
```

Rails does not create files outside the directory so you just have to remove the folder.